# How to improve iterations runtime in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, recommendation-engine

I am trying to build a recommendation engine to recommend products to the customers according to their buying history.

The code I am using currently is as follows:

```
#drop the user column for now
df1 = df.drop('ID', 1)  

data_ibs = pd.DataFrame(index=df1.columns,columns=df1.columns)

#Let's fill in those empty spaces with cosine similarities

#Loop through the columns
for i in range(0,len(data_ibs.columns)) :

#Loop through the columns for each column
  for j in range(0,len(data_ibs.columns)):
    data_ibs.ix[i,j] = 1-cosine(df1.ix[:,i],df1.ix[:,j]) #Fill in placeholder with cosine similarities

# Create a placeholder items for closes neighbours to an item
data_neighbours = pd.DataFrame(index=data_ibs.columns,columns=range(1,8)) 

# Loop through our similarity dataframe and fill in neighbouring item names
for i in range(0,len(data_ibs.columns)):
  data_neighbours.ix[i,:7] = data_ibs.ix[0:,i].order(ascending=False)[:7].index

# --- End Item Based Recommendations --- # 

# --- Start User Based Recommendations --- #

# Helper function to get similarity scores
def getScore(history, similarities):
  return sum(history*similarities)/sum(similarities) 

# Create a place holder matrix for similarities, and fill in the user name column
data_sims = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index,columns=df.columns)
data_sims.ix[:,0] = df.ix[:,0]
```

Up to now it run smoothly without any problems, but when I run the next step, it takes a long time to produce the result and I do not know how long will it take until it finishes.

```
#Loop through all rows, skip the user column, and fill with similarity scores
for i in range(0,len(data_sims.index)):
  for j in range(1,len(data_sims.columns)):
    user = data_sims.index[i]
    product = data_sims.columns[j]
    if df.iloc[i,j] >= 1:
      data_sims.iloc[i,j] = 0
    else:
      product_top_names = data_neighbours.ix[product][1:7]
      product_top_sims = data_ibs.ix[product].order(ascending=False)[1:7]
      user_purchases = df.ix[user,product_top_names]
      data_sims.ix[i, j] = getScore(user_purchases,product_top_sims)
```

I tried to use a small subset of the data and I confirmed it is working properly. However, when I try with the whole dataset which is some 4 million rows, it stucked for a long time and may take a day or so to finish.

Can you find the piece/pieces of my code which slow the process or if possible I would appreciate if you could suggest a better way to improve the runtime compared to the current method.

Comment: You have N^2 similarities to calculate. It is simply an O(N^2) problem, no matter how you approach it. For 4 mln rows, it's 16 trilllion function calls. Pandas is not to blame, but it won't help, either. Do you really want to calculate all similarities ahead of time? Would lazy on demand calculation + caching be appropriate?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It is not intended to calculate ahead of time, but to get an insight of the accuracy of our predictions against the test data.

Comment: try using `map`, list comprehensions, multithreading, multiprocessing

Comment: I did run the program for eight hours and it processed only 5% of the data.
This means that I need to wait for nine days until this program finish processing the whole data. You want to tell me that this is normal?